# What is the reason for core dump in my function (detect_duplicates) to be specific?

Tags: c++

I have 3 functions here, and the compiler is going through the first 2 functions, but it is not entering the 3rd function(detect_duplicates).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head = NULL;

void createLL(int a[], int n)
{
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = a[0];
    head->next = NULL;
    struct node *t, *last;
    last = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        t = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        t->data = a[i];
        t->next = NULL;
        last->next = t;
        last = t;
    }
}

void printList(struct node* head_ref)
{
    printf("Linked list : {");
    while (head_ref != NULL) {
        printf(" %d ", head_ref->data);
        head_ref = head_ref->next;
    }
    printf("}\n");
}

void detect_duplicates(struct node* head, int size)
{
    int x, y;
    struct node *temp, *temp2;
    temp = head;
    cout << "Duplicate elements are : ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        x = temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
        temp2 = temp;
        while (temp2->next != NULL) {
            y = temp2->data;
            if (x == y) {
                cout << y << " ";
            }
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int Linked_list[30] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 }, size = 11;

    createLL(Linked_list, size);
    cout << "Input ";
    printList(head);

    detect_duplicates(head, size);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a program to detect the duplicate elements from an integer linked list. I can't figure out the error in my detect_duplicates function and also my compiler isn't showing a known error. It is just showing a Segmentation fault.

Comment: I think `temp2` can be null here: `while (temp2->next != NULL) {` if it is you are dereferencing a null pointer with the condition `temp2->next != NULL`

Comment: `iostream`, `cout`, `namespace` are invalid C. Why was the correct C++ tag changed to C?

Comment: "Please correct me asap". You might want to read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to access the `next` of `temp2` in

```
temp2 = temp;
while (temp2->next != NULL) {
    y = temp2->data;
    if (x == y) {
    cout << y << " ";
}
```

temp2 can be a `nullptr` which may cause a segmentation fault, because it points to nothing and you are trying to access it's member.

Comment: But how can temp2 be a nullptr, anything wrong with my loop conditions?

Comment: @AlexBaby in the `for` loop when `i==size-1`.

Comment: I think that you should not have used size at all in detect_duplicates() instead you should have had a while loop in the outer loop.